# Handle a click event on a button in C# with Razor and MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

how can I handle an event which is triggered in a view from a different controller class/file?

Controller class (where the event is supposed to be handled):

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TestApp.Models;

namespace TestApp.Controllers
{
public class HelloWorldController : Controller
{
    // GET: HelloWorld

    Movie movie;

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        movie = new Movie();
        setMovie();

        ViewBag.Message = "ID: " + movie.ID + "\r\nTitle: " + movie.Title +
            "\r\nRelease Date: " + movie.ReleaseDate + "\r\n: " + movie.Price;



        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Welcome(string name, int numTimes = 1) {
        ViewBag.Message = "Hello" + name;
        ViewBag.NumTimes = numTimes;

        return View();
    }

    public void modifyMovieClicked()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("test");
    }

    private void setMovie()
    {
        movie.ID = 9821;
        movie.Title = "Scarface";
        movie.ReleaseDate = "October 20";
        movie.Price = 85;

    }
}
}
```

View Class(where the html button is defined)

```
@using TestApp.Controllers;

@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Movie List";
}

@{ 
HelloWorldController controller = new HelloWorldController();

void clickedButton()
{
    controller.modifyMovieClicked();
}
}


<h2>My Movie List</h2>

<p>
   @ViewBag.Message
</p>

<button id= "modifyButton" runat ="server" 
 onserverclick="clickedButton"> Modify movie</button>
```

When clicked, the html button is supposed to call the clickedButton method so this method can call the event handler in the other file, but this doesnt happen. Any help is appreciated

Comment: There is no such thing as `runat ="server"` in mvc. You need to handle the buttons `.click()` event in javascript/jquery and make an ajax call to the server method.

Comment: I think you should probably spend some more time with the basic architecture of ASP.NET MVC, especially with the topic "which code lives *when* and *where*".

Answer (score 2):

In `MVC` pattern `View` and `Controller` are separate concept and you can not use `runat="server"` and define `click_event` in server side. You can use `JavaScript or jQuery` for do it like this:

```
<input type="text" id="MovieName" />
<button id= "modifyButton" onclick="ModifyMovie()"> Modify movie</button>    

<script>
    function ModifyMovie() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("modifyMovieClicked","HelloWorld")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { movieName: $('#MovieName').val() },
        }).done(function () {
            alert('Modify Movie');
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Edit**

You can pass parameter to server side method with by set `data`. For example I added to my html code a input with `id="MovieName"` and get value of it by `$('#MovieName').val()` and set `movieName` property by this `movieName: $('#MovieName').val()` and finally pass to server side method below by `data`:

```
public void modifyMovieClicked(string movieName)
{    
  // your code           
}
```

Comment: what if I want to send some data from an html input textform to the modifyMovieClicked method with Javascript?

Comment: @RodrigoPeniche I added example for pass data to server side method. Please see this. Hope to help you.

Comment: @RodrigoPeniche Please accept this answer if it helps you, so people know this is the correct answer and helps them.